# Destructuring assignment appears to affect variable that occurs before it, during an async call

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have the following event handler inside a React class component.

```
    eventHandler = async location => {
        console.log("Location is:", location) // location is displayed as expected
        
        this.setState({}, async () => {
            console.log('Location is', location); // location is undefined
            const {location, weather, temperature } = {'location':'Laos'};
            console.log('location is', location); // location is displayed as expected (Laos)
        });
    };
```

I notice that location becomes undefined because of the destructuring assignment in the next line. Reassigning the variable to 'place' in the destructuring like so `const {location:place, weather, temperature } = {}`, fixes the issue.

I would like to understand why the destructuring statement affects that variable at all, in code that appears before the destructuring occurs.

Comment: Because of hoisting. It doesn't "become" `undefined`--you shadow the `location` parameter by declaring a *new* `location` in the `setState` callback. It *is* `undefined` before you... define it.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an error "cannot access 'location' before initialization". I guess it's getting transpiled to `var`s` instead of `const`s.

Comment: @NicholasTower Or a reference error, which is what I would have expected (temporal dead zone)

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables named `location`. Since `const`s are scoped to the block they are inside of, any code in that inner function will be interacting with the inner variable, not the outer one. As a result, you're trying to access the inner variable before you've given it a value.

I would expect the code to actually throw a ReferenceError, saying that you "cannot access 'location' before initialization". The fact that it's not could be explained if this code is getting transpiled and thus is using `var`s instead of `consts`. With vars, you still have the same problem that the inner code is accessing only the inner variable, but it doesn't throw an exception, just gives you undefined.

When you rename the variable, then there's no longer a conflict. `location` could only ever refer to the outer variable, and `place` could only ever refer to the inner one.